# Copying XML-data from Excel results in wrong data in clipboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

I have an Excel spreadsheet with XML data in the cells. When I copy the data with `CTRL + C` without being in the cell editing mode, I get data in clipboard but this data is wrong. The data in the clipboard does contain additional `"` symbols.

An **example** to reproduce this:

Go to this site: http://www.service-architecture.com/articles/object-oriented-databases/xml_file_for_complex_data.html . Copy the shown XML data and paste it in cell editing mode in Excel so that the whole XML data is in one cell. Disable text wrapping for this cell. Copy the data from Excel cell and paste it in notepad. You will see additional `"` and the XML structure becomes invalid.

What can I do about this and is there some kind of cell formating for XML content?

System: 
Windows 7 
Microsoft Office 365

Comment: Not sure why you would use Excel as an XML editor, but the problem is due to Excel considering your XML as text, the easiest way is to "simply" delete these speech marks from your XML manually. There are only 2, one at the start and one at the end so this will be very quick.

Comment: I use Excel for XML and other content. The fle contains test data/test scenarios for an application. No, sadly it isn't only at beginning and end of it. In reality, it put's also `"` around values of specific attributes.

Comment: There are hundreds of better XML programs for coding XML, Excel is excellent as a spreadsheet but for XML I would use Notepad over Excel.

Comment: Well, I don't code in it, I just copy and paste input and output and write down the results. The input and output is XML in specific cases, so we have to do it like that.

Comment: If you *have* to do it in Excel, you could paste the XML into Word first and find/replace the "s with nothing.